# Using the Advertising ID

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-advertising-id

I'm having problems with google play because I have google admob with interstitials.

I have to implement this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html#get_started in unity, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is my code where I request the Add:

```
void Start () {     
    // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-2682144290513842/3941226367");
    // Create an empty ad request.
    request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the interstitial with the request.
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}

void showAdd(){
    if(Random.Range(0,5)>3){
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/games

Comment: Everything looks correct. What problem do you have with Google play?

Comment: @William the problems seems that I have to implement the user preferences when I request the advertisment.

Comment: What specific error are you getting?